# Youtube API get_video_info & url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api, html5-video, google-api-php-client

Starting from the YouTube API **get_video_info**, I'm retrieving from a PHP code the **url_encoded_fmt_stream_map**

Everything was fine until this morning when suddenly the fmt_stream automagically decided to get only the following formats:

```
mp4@hd720
x-flv@large
webm@medium
x-flv@medium
mp4@medium
x-flv@small
3gpp@small
```

What is missing, in fact, is:

```
webm@large
webm@hd720
```

These 2 are the formats that I need in my website.

Yesterday at 18:00 (more or less) I was still able to get them but not this morning; today, after 1 day of investigation, I have no clue about the problem!

I'm a newbie with PHP and the code that I'm using was written by someone else...I just need to figured it out how to get **webm@large** and **webm@hd720** again!

Any help is really apprecieted!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the EaseIt API could help you with this, it's a very powerfull API that provides a full view related to a video ID.

**It contains some of this points in response:**

1. url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

   - Main video and audio formats
2. adaptive_fmts

   - Contains an alternative quality of video and audio (Like: Combined video 1080p and audio, Combined video 720p and Audio, Just video 1080p, Just video 720p, Just video 480p, Just audio m4a, etc.)
3. rvs

   - Related Video's
4. player_response:

   - It contains more information details about the video (Like: status, ADS, adPlacements, annotations, storyboards, messages, endscreen, subtitles, etc.)

Example: https://api.easeit.online/darklight/gvi?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1_VsyLAGuk